# SystemCoreClockUpdate() function not recognized in STM32L476rg CubeIDE project

Tags: c, stm32

I am following a Udemy RTOS course, its about how to build an rtos from scratch on stm32 bords, so when following the videos i called the SystemCoreClockUpdate() function but it was not recognized by the compiler, I added these paths to the project sittings:
-CMSIS/include
-CMSIS/Core/include
-CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Include
this function is declared in system_stm32l4xx.c and has a prototype declared as extern in system_stm32l4xx.h file
what should i include to make this work ?
here's the code

```
#include "stm32l476xx.h"
#include "uart.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void SystemClockConfig(void);
void DelayS(uint32_t seconds);

volatile uint32_t tick;
volatile uint32_t _tick;

int main(void) {

    SystemClockConfig();
    while(1)
    {
        printf("hello");
        DelayS(1);
    }
}

void SystemClockConfig(void) {
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 100U);
    __enable_irq();
}

void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    ++tick;
}
uint32_t getTick(void) {
    __disable_irq();
    _tick = tick;
    __enable_irq();
    return _tick;
}

void DelayS(uint32_t seconds) {
    seconds *= 100;
    uint32_t temp = getTick();
    while ((getTick() - temp) < seconds) {
    }

}
```

I tried including system_stm32xx.h and the core_cm4.h but nothing changed

Comment: Do not use unrelated tags. `Compiler-errors` is for errors in the compiler itself, not in your program.

Answer (score 0):

> what should i include to make this work? I tried including
> system_stm32xx.h and the core_cm4.h but nothing changed

As this function was not intended to be called from the application code directly (it is called via `HAL_RCC...` functions), no headers contain its prototype.

Simply add the prototype before the main (you need to compile and link the appropriate C file too).

```
void SystemCoreClockUpdate(void);
```

Did the Udemy teacher advise you to do this?:

```
uint32_t getTick(void) {
    __disable_irq();
    _tick = tick;
    __enable_irq();
    return _tick;
}
```

32bit read is atomic on Cortex-M targets and you do not have to disable interrupts (BTW you should do it only if it is essential)

Do not disable interrupt yourself if you use freeRTOS - `taskENTER_CRITICAL()` and `taskEXIT_CRITICAL()`

`100U` - 'U' is not needed

Comment: the course is about building your own rtos from scratch, i'll try to do what you told me thanks, and yes he advised to do so because in assembly this line of code will be divided into 3 instructions, we want them all to be done one after another, we disabled interrupts to not interrupt this order, thats what he said

Comment: @RaedBanneni no, RMW (`tick++;`)statement is executed in 3 steps (in this case 3 instructions). Read is only one. He unfortunately is wrong. BTW declaring `_tick` as global and `volatile` is also wrong. This variable (_tick) is not needed too. https://godbolt.org/z/shzYsGGzK